# Generating hard satisfiability problems with given constraint graph

Tags: graph-theory, sat, phase-transition, random-k-sat, max2sat

Is there a systematic way to tune the hardness of a set of satisfiability problems (say 3-SAT or MAX2SAT) where the constraint graphs are always embeddable into a fixed given graph?

Comment: In the paper "When is the evaluation of conjunctive queries tractable?" of Grohe et al. (STOC '01) it is proved that if C is a class of graphs with unbounded treewidth, then one can embed arbitrarily hard CSP problems to graphs in C. (and conversely, of course, if C has bounded treewidth then CSP in C can be solved in polytime). I have not read the paper completely, but it sounds something highly related to your question, so I think you should check if it answers to your question.

Comment: Though this paper seems to not help much if you are interested in something practical because it relies on the grid-minor theorem.

Comment: @Laakeri, it seems my setup is exactly opposite to the setup in grid-minor theorem. In the grid-minor theorem, the larger graph is arbitrary and the graph to be embedded is a grid. In my case, the larger graph has constrained topology (e.g. a grid) but the graph to be embedded could be arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want are [universal factor graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6484). Such graphs exist for [every NP-hard boolean CSP](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2014/4702/pdf/19.pdf) and in many cases are [optimally inapproximable](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2019/151/).